# tcl/expect install on UNIX (ClearOS)

Tags: unix, tcl

I am trying to install expect package on my ClearOS server.

I tried:

```
yum install tcl
yum install expect
```

Both return "ERROR: xz compression not available"

The repositories I have enabled are:

```
clearos 
clearos-addons 
clearos-extras 
clearos-updates 
clearos-updates 
epel 
epel 
rpmforge 
webtatic
```

Can anybody tell me what is wrong? My knowledge of servers is also pretty limited.

Comment: This belongs on the http://unix.stackexchange.com site. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I've fixed the problem. The error was caused by the foreign repositories that I have added hoping they will contain tcl and expect packages.
   So I removed them and the yum is working again.

```
rm -rf /etc/yum.repos.d/epel*
rm -rf /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmforge*
rm -rf /etc/yum.repos.d/webtatic*
```

Nevertheless this got rid of the issue with yum, I still cannot find the expect package. If anyone knows how to install this, please let me know...